# How to integrate Dispatch Luis.ai in MS Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I created a project using Bot Builder Visual Studio 2015.
In `RootDialog.cs`, added  `[LuisModel("<Luis- appid>","<key>")]` it was working before I did dispatch. Because I had used only Luis APPId and key. But after I dispatched `LUIS` and `QnA Maker` it created `Dispatched` Application in Luis Portal.

[image]

Now I changed `Luis App Id` in `LuisModel()` as Dispatched Application Id. And **Published** app. But, it throwing **The given key was not present in the dictionary**. An endpoint of the dispatched application is working fine. But, app id is not working in c# bot framework.

Comment: Is the bot using the authoring/starter key as the endpoint key for LUIS or is the bot using an Azure resource Language Understanding key for the endpoint? If it is the second one, make sure you add the LUIS key to the new dispatch app in the Manage -> keys and endpoints.

Comment: @DFBerry I took authoring key from LUIS.ai

Comment: @DFBerry found the issue, its because that Luis app is created using outlook account and QnA app created in an organization account. But, still getting confused , how the endpoints working.